# How can I undo last command in command line?

Tags: command-line, vim-windows, tabbed-user-interface, undo-redo

In general, is there a way to UNDO the last "meta" command (I mean a command entered in command line to manage a window ), or some equivalent keystroke sequence ?

Btw, I know the `u` (= undo) and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> (= redo) works for commands that edits/changes a file content. Ok, but:

Let consider the scenario in screenshot here attached, where I'm editing multiple files in a multiwindow/multitab:

[image: multiple window in vim screenshot]

Now, let say for example that I enter for typo or error a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> to exlicitly edit `:only` and afterward I would UNDO, to go back to last window layout.

Is there a command/keystroke to go back o the previous window layout ?

I know that I can use `:ball` (reshow all buffers each in a window horizontally splitted) or `:vert ball` (same with vertical split), but in this way I loss all windows layout setting (window resized/personalized, visual window sequence, etc.)

More in general, how can I undo commands entered in command line or using some keystroke sequence alias ?

I'm aware of course that some commands are pretty "irreversible"; like `:w` for example, but I'd love a UNDO for many commands that just manage layout/buffers/"in-memory" work.

Comment: No, there is no command to reverse `:only` and no generic way to undo Ex commands.

Comment: Related plugin: [ZoomWin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=508)

Comment: @Peter Rinker thanks! ZoomWin make me happy. BTW last version 25: https://github.com/regedarek/ZoomWin I voted also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194428/is-better-way-to-zoom-windows-in-vim-than-zoomwin